# Incomplete Search Results With Google Search API V1

Tags: c#, google-custom-search, google-search-api

So I set up my API key and my Search Engine ID and my Custom Search to include the entire web using this [post](http://hintdesk.com/c-how-to-use-google-custom-search-api/) as a reference. The problem is that when I do a search using the C# code the api only returns a resultset of 10 whereas I do the search in a google browser page, google returns me 700+ results. Is this by design? If so what is the purpose of the new api? it's basically worthless. My use case is I have to return a set of results using an "AllInText: *[search criteria]*" so that the company can validate any sites that contain their company information. If I'm only returning less than .02% of the results this will do me nothing. Does anyone have any suggestions for alternatives? Am I doing something wrong that is limiting my result set?

Comment: Suppose your query's result were 1M hits. Should google return it in one response?

Comment: No I wouldn't. But I would expect it to tell me that there were 1M hits and allow me to retrieve them in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify listRequest.Start for every query
first:

```
listRequest.Start = 1;
```

second:

```
listRequest.Start = 11;
```

etc..

Comment: I do modify the .Start to retrieve the next set of results but I'm more concerned at the total results. A Google search from their search page will show over 200 results for a certain request but the search api will only show 18 for the same request.

Comment: Also results from API and from web search are different. And i don't know how to fix this